# What are the disadvantages of models with many parameters to tune?

Tags: machine-learning, random-forest, boosting

I modeled with 3 different methods but all showed bad accuracy. So im trying to reason why! one of the issues might be the many parameters that i tuned. So i want to know if there are disadvantages in using models with many parameters to tune?

Comment: can you elaborate on the nature of the problem(regression or classifiation), quality of the variables used and results obtained? Poor results may be due to a number of factors and not just hyperparameters

Comment: it's a classification problem with 25 predictors and 181 observations, the result was less than 30% accuracy .. the variables were correlated at some extent.

Answer (score -1):

Does this comment from [a source](https://www.jstor.org/stable/1909769?seq=1), possibly capture your state of modeling:

> The problems involved in obtaining meaningful coefficients of regression by the method of least squares with such intercorrelated data are well known [2, 13, 21]

A potential solution, apply Factor Analysis to construct variables as in this work ['Use of factor scores in multiple regression analysis for estimation of body weight by certain body measurements in Romanov Lambs'](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC6679909/) and also a [related work here](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/pdf/10.1080/09712119.2007.9706664).

One can also look into a more advanced work on Factor Analysis Regression, which may be appropriate to [quote a source](https://www.jstor.org/stable/1909769?seq=1):

> Factor analysis appears to be a particularly appropriate tool in the field of economics where many “independent” variables have high intercorrelation and where there are errors in all the variables .

Also, more pertinent comments relating to coefficients, which differ from more facilely generated Least-Squares Regression parameters:

> Stochastic linear equations can be obtained from factor analysis which give better coefficients (better from the standpoint of their economic meaning and their theoretical expectation) then do regression equations obtained through a traditional least squares squares [9].

which, in my opinion, is quite a powerful and important assertion.